# Extract value from column of nested dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have below data frame. need to create a third column to `bool` and add the all the bool values into that

```
>>> df[['col2']]
    0   {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': True}}}
    1   {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': False}}}

>>> type(df[['col2']]) # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
>>> df[['col2']['result']['is_doc1']['bool']]
('list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

>>> type(df['col2']) # pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: Remove the nested lists `df[['col1','col2' ]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an object column, it should support `.str` accessor methods:

```
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str['result'].str['is_doc1'].str['bool']
df 
                                       col2   col3
0   {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': True}}}   True
1  {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': False}}}  False
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
[x['result']['is_doc1']['bool'] for x in df['col2']]
# [True, False]

df['col3'] = [x['result']['is_doc1']['bool'] for x in df['col2']])
df
                                       col2   col3
0   {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': True}}}   True
1  {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': False}}}  False
```

---

If "col2" is a column of strings, start by parsing it first:

```
import ast
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Here's a more robust version:

```
def try_parse(string):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(string)
    except ValueError, SyntaxError:
        return np.nan

df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(try_parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to acces the dictionary in your column. One way to solve this is to use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Bool'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x['result']['is_doc1']['bool'])

                                       col2   Bool
0   {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': True}}}   True
1  {'result': {'is_doc1': {'bool': False}}}  False
```